# Failover or replication with an OpenVPN server?

Tags: openvpn

Is it possible to implement two OpenVPN with failover and replication capability? As in, if one is down/fails, the other one is avaliable for authentification, server/client configuration, etc. ?

Answer (score 5):

I failed to understand why to shoot from cannon to the fly. IHMO there's a simpler way:
To use build-in OpenVPN features and linux iproute2 for multipath redundancy. I'll be safer, more stable and less resource consuming.

Source: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

Implementing a load-balancing/failover configuration
Client

The OpenVPN client configuration can refer to multiple servers for load balancing and failover. For example:

```
remote server1.mydomain
remote server2.mydomain
remote server3.mydomain
```

will direct the OpenVPN client to attempt a connection with server1, server2, and server3 in that order. If an existing connection is broken, the OpenVPN client will retry the most recently connected server, and if that fails, will move on to the next server in the list. You can also direct the OpenVPN client to randomize its server list on startup, so that the client load will be probabilistically spread across the server pool.

```
remote-random
```

If you would also like DNS resolution failures to cause the OpenVPN client to move to the next server in the list, add the following:

```
resolv-retry 60
```

The 60 parameter tells the OpenVPN client to try resolving each remote DNS name for 60 seconds before moving on to the next server in the list.

The server list can also refer to multiple OpenVPN server daemons running on the same machine, each listening for connections on a different port, for example:

```
remote smp-server1.mydomain 8000
remote smp-server1.mydomain 8001
remote smp-server2.mydomain 8000
remote smp-server2.mydomain 8001
```

If your servers are multi-processor machines, running multiple OpenVPN daemons on each server can be advantageous from a performance standpoint.

OpenVPN also supports the remote directive referring to a DNS name which has multiple A records in the zone configuration for the domain. In this case, the OpenVPN client will randomly choose one of the A records every time the domain is resolved.
Server

The simplest approach to a load-balanced/failover configuration on the server is to use equivalent configuration files on each server in the cluster, except use a different virtual IP address pool for each server. For example:

server1

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

server2

```
server 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

server3

```
server 10.8.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: The last paragraph is my issue: They would have to be all on the same address pool to be able to access resources and subnets. If not, on each server I would have to configure iroute and route pushing...not ideal IMO.

Comment: You can bypass it using; bridge, tap & dhcpd. Including pushing routes. Compatibility: everything excluding MacOS.

Comment: For reference of dhcpd configuration please look @ my post: http://superuser.com/questions/874671/how-can-i-inform-mac-os-and-ios-clients-of-vpn-routes

Answer (score 0):

Failover?  Yes, I do it all the time, using heartbeat and CRM.  It's not worth trying to replicate or preserve state; when the failover happens, all connected clients will reauthenticate anyway, and that's fine for road-warriors.  It wouldn't be fine for site-to-site VPNs, but (imho) OpenVPN is the wrong tool for those, anyway.

Comment: heartbeat is deprecated, corosync+crm is a good solution

Comment: Excellent recommendation, I'm sure; mostly I was establishing that it can be done, and is in some quarters fairly normal practice.  **How** you do it might be an OT question!

Comment: Ive searched Google and Ive found some information but this is personally beyond my personal scope. Could you explain how exactly it works and how it is implemented?

Comment: No.  That's way outside the scope of an SF question, and I'd've voted to close if you'd asked it (too broad).  You need to do your own research and learning.  When you've tried, and have specific questions resulting from that attempt, SF may well be a good place to ask them.

Comment: Then really, your response helps 0. Michal Sokolowski not only gives a better solution, but also explains how to implement it.

Comment: I don't agree that Michal's method is better, but it will work fine as I understand it, and yes, he explains it very well.  That doesn't alter the fact that SF isn't for step-by-step learning guides, or HOWTOs; it's for getting expert answers to specific sysadmin problems.  I've answered the question as you asked it, and given you some pointers for your research, to which c4f4t0r has made a valuable annotation.  If you'd started off by asking for a step-by-step guide, I'd've voted to close the question; trying to turn this into a HOWTO request after the fact doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: Doesnt matter if you dont agree; It answers the question and explains how to implement it. The point of the site is to help out.